# SpotifyAPI-NET add scope console application c#

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, spotify

I'm using this library

https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET

In a console application in order to authenticate myself then create one playlist

```
public async Task CreatePlaylist(string playlistName)
{
    CredentialsAuth auth = new CredentialsAuth(_clientId, _clientSecret);
    Token token = await auth.GetToken();

    SpotifyWebAPI api = new SpotifyWebAPI()
    {
        TokenType = token.TokenType,
        AccessToken = token.AccessToken
    };

    FullPlaylist playlist = api.CreatePlaylist(_userId, "This is my new Playlist");
    if (!playlist.HasError())
        Console.WriteLine("Playlist-URI: " + playlist.Uri);
}
```

I got this error: 403 - This request requires user authentication

I know that I have to add scope playlist-modify-public into my request but I don't understand how to do that

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use Authentication with that scope, for this library there is a **AuthorizationCodeAuth** and **ImplicitGrantAuth** which are the two authentication types you may need as those provide user authentication to create a playlist. I've not used this particular library but you can find details at [SpotifyAPI.Web.Auth](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET/tree/master/SpotifyAPI.Web.Auth)

> Full disclosure I do have my own Spotify Library independent to this one